# How to deserialize JSON string when field name and/or value contain white space leading/tailing by using jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Input json:

```
{"id   ": "   1"}
```

java class defineded:

```
class ID {
    String id;
}
```

how to correctly get the ID object with "id = 1" instead of  "id = null"

Comment: will the number of spaces around `id` always be the same?

Comment: No, it depends on user input

Comment: The best way for key `id` would be to `trim()` the user input in your frontend app. As for the value `1`, you can trim it in the controller.

Comment: Hi @Kartik, the input is from others' java code and my code can't relay on others' code for some reason. So there is no frontend. For now, the only solution I can do is receiving the input as a map, and format every element in the map, then convert them to my object. But it is not graceful I think

Answer (score 3):

You may use `@JsonProperty` annotation like this:

```
class ID {

    @JsonProperty("id   ")
    String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
String id = myIdClassInstance.getId().trim();
```

But this will work only in cases where the number of spaces is fixed.

Also, you can access the fields of the object only at clearly defined names.

If you really want that `"id"` and `"id    "` to point to the same field, you will need to format the JSON manually before sending it.

Comment: The number of spaces is not fixed. I'm using @RequestBody annotation on an object argument of spring boot controller method. So how to manually format the input?  Thank you

Comment: @Alex, you are forming the JSON using the JavaScript before sending, right? You can do it like this: `{ [idName]: idValue, ... }`, where `var idName = 'id     '.trim(); var idValue = '     1'.trim()`

Comment: Hi Artiow, the input is from others' java code and my code can't relay on others' code for some reason

Comment: YOU SAVED MY ASS THANK YOU MY DEAR Artiow

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is better to edit JSON beforehand and remove extra spaces.

```
var json = "{\"id   \": \"   1\"}";
json = json.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

You'll get: `{"id":"1"}`
And then your POJO class will be correct.

After you can try to deserialize this json via Jackson. For example:

```
var id = mapper.readValue(json, ID.class);
```